# Ideal Skip list ? O(n) run-time?

Tags: algorithm, linked-list, skip-lists

I'm trying to find the best algorithm for

```
converting an "ordinary" linked list 
into an `ideal skip list`
```

.

Where the definition of an `ideal skip list` is that in the first level we'll have all 
the elements , in the level above - half of them , the one after - quarter of them ... and so on .

I'm thinking about `O(n)` run-time where involving throwing a coin for each node in 
the original linked-list , whether or not for a specific node , should I go up or not , and create another duplicate node for the current node upstairs ...
Eventually this algorithm would produce O(n)  , is there any better algorithm ?

Regards

Comment: See the [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list) for the randomized algorithm you mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming the linked list is sorted - otherwise it cannot be done in comparison based algorithm, since you need to sort it in `Omega(nlogn)`

- Iterate on the "highest level" of the list, and add a "link up node" every second node.
- Repeat until the highest level has only one node.

The idea is to generate a new list, half the size of the original, which is linked to the original in every 2nd link, and then recursively invoke on the smaller list, until you reach a list of size 1.

You will end up with lists of size 1,2,4,...,n/2 linked to each other.

**pseudo code:**

```
makeSkipList(list):
  if (list == null || list.next == null): //stop clause - a list of size 1
      return
//root is the next level list, which will have n/2 elements.
  root <- new link node
  root.linkedNode <- list //linked node is linking "down" in the skip list.
  root.next <- null //next is linking "right" in the skip list.
  lastLinkNode <- root
  i <- 1
//we create a link every second element
  for each node in list, exlude the first element:
     if (i++ %2 == 0): //for every 2nd element, create a link node.
         lastLinkNode.next <- new link node 
         lastLinkNode <- lastLinkNode.next //setting the "down" field to the element in the list
         lastLinkNode.linkedNode <- node 
         lastLinkNode.next <- null
   makeSkipList(root) //recursively invoke on the new list, which is of size n/2.
```

Complexity is O(n) since the algorithm complexity can be described as `T(n) = n + T(n/2)`, thus you get `T(n) = n + n/2 + n/4 + ... -> 2n`

It is easy to see it cannot be done better then `O(n)`, because at the very least you will have to add at least one node in the second half of the original list, and getting there is itself `O(n)`

Comment: What do you mean by "highest level" ? I start at level 0 (complete original linked list) and then I take the one after the first node , i.e I take and node after the "head" , and then I go up and place a new node for the it ,upstairs ? your algorithm is not so clear to me....can you please explain ?

Comment: @ron: I editted the answer and added a commented pseudo code describing a recursive function, the idea is - create a links for your skip list of size n/2, and then recursively invoke on your smaller list, until you get a list of size 1, you will end up with lists of size: 1, 2, 4, .... , n/2, n